# NIC teaming windows 2008 R2

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge

Can assist me in NIC teaming on windows server 2008 standard R2 SP1 on the Dell PowerEdge R320 and R720 Server.

I have done NIC teaming for load balancing on WinServer 2012 but unable to get it on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and the card used on the Server is Broadcom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, guess what is a feature in 2012 "WHat is New"`? Hint - it is NIC teaming.

Pre 2012 there is no operating system level NIC teaming.

That does not mean there is NO nic teaming - just not by the OS. Head over to broadcom and get the latest driver and read the documentation. If you are lucky they can do NIC-Teaming in the driver. Intel CAN do that.

A little google returned to me:

http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/management_applications.php
and a youtube video about how to cereate NIC teaming with Broadcom drivers:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2nq-qEwAzg

But generally - upgrading to 2012 is the way to go.

Comment: thank you for your valuble time folks..really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan already wrote, server 2008 R2 does not have **native** NIC teaming.  You can team NICs only if the vendors driver supports this. Some do, some do not.

As for your specific NICs. Just stating that it is a Broadcom is a bit to generic. Much akin to "I need to repair my cars battery. It is a Volvo", without specifying a specific model.

Searching for Dell R320 NIC makes me suspect that you are using the Broadcom NetXtreme. According to [this FAQ](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/faq_drivers.php) on the Broadcom website you can team those as follows:

```
In the Control Panel, click Broadcom Advanced Control Suite.
Select Teams from the menu, and select "Go to Team View". 

 To create a new team, select Create Team from the Team menu
 or right-click one of the devices in the "Unassigned Adapters" section
 and select Create Team.

  A teaming wizard will display. Follow the instructions in the wizard and
  and then click Finish to create the desired teaming configuration.
```

If you did not yet install the Broadcom drivers, do so now (sometime windows will find and use its own drivers, and then functionality will differ).

Answer (score 1):

Server 2008 R2 doesn't have native NIC teaming, this is a new feature in 2012.